# Wait by duration time frame

Tags: wait-element

My question would be if I’m doing a journey and first email is set to go out on Monday 9am, then I insert a wait by duration for 1 day for the next email. Now the next email will go out on Tuesday or Wednesday? I don’t really get the “one day” attribute meaning. One day from the email sent on Monday, or will it give you one day of rest and then send the next one?

Answer (score 0):

Technology uses the same English that we do. If there was a rest period of a day, the interface would say "rest one day." In pretty much all technology everywhere that uses English, it universally represents "24 hours from some time" and not "wait until midnight, wait 24 hours, then do something." Such a technology would be pretty useless and confusing, because it doesn't conform to the colloquial use of time.